# Taylor series representation of Planck's law

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

I am to find the Taylor series for Planck's law, $$\frac{8\pi \:hc\lambda ^{-5}}{e^{\frac{hc}{\lambda \:kt}}-1}$$
T is temperature, h, c, and k are constants, and $$\lambda $$ is wavelength. I am supposed to show that Planck's law gives an approximation of Raleigh-Jeans law at large wavelengths.
first derivative is $$\frac{40\pi \:kt\lambda \:^{-4}}{e^{\frac{hc}{kt\lambda \:}}}$$ (as far as I can tell)
The next, I think, is $$\frac{160\pi \:k^2t^2}{che^{\frac{ch}{kt\lambda }}\lambda ^3}$$
But I am unsure of what value to set $$ a  $$ to, in the formula $$ f(x)=f(a)+f'(a)/1!*(x-a)+f''(a)/2!*(x-a)^2... $$
Do I use a Maclaurin series? would that mean setting $$\lambda$$ to 0? Is $$ \lambda$$ equivalent to a?

Comment: You're thinking too much. All you really need to do is to take the leading order expansion of $e^{\frac{hc}{\lambda kt}}$ at $\lambda=\infty$, which is equivalent to expanding $e^x$ at $x=0$ and plugging in $x=\frac{hc}{\lambda kt}$, with $\lambda \gg \frac{hc}{kt}$. A technicality arises because the first term in the expansion is cancelled by the $-1$, so the leading order contribution is in fact the $\lambda^{-1}$ term.

Comment: The approximation is for large wavelengths, so you should probably take $\lambda \to \infty$

Comment: What is a? Is it centered at a→∞?

Comment: Could you please check the formula for derivative that you have used? $\left(\frac{f}{g}\right)'\ne\frac{f'}{g'}$

Comment: Isn't that l'hospital's rule?

Comment: No, L'hospital's rule is entirely different. You need the quotient rule to get the derivative of a quotient. But you don't need that here either.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a summary of the comments:

1. Large wavelengths means that $\lambda$ is much larger than $0$. You need to expand in the limit $\lambda\rightarrow\infty$.
2. Obviously the MacLaurin expansion will have issues in this case, since you will have terms as powers of$(x-\infty)$. If you need to go along this route, your variable should be $1/\lambda$, which in the case of long wavelengths goes to $0$. You have then $x=1/\lambda$ and $$f(x)=\frac{8\pi h c x^5}{e^{\frac{hc}{kT} x}-1}$$
3. **You need to calculate the derivatives correctly**

The simplest way to solve this problem is to note that for small $x$, $e^{\frac{hc}{kT} x}\approx 1+\frac{hc}{kT} x$